# PHP: 'Intelligent' absolute paths vs relative path

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm writing a Router class for a library of mine.
This class will keep the locations of some paths, but I'm wondering if I should use 'intelligent' absolute paths, relative paths or both (for this case) will be the same thing.

Obs.1: When I wrote *'intelligent' absolute path* is because this absolute path will work even if the admin move the library to another location.

Obs.2: Stack has other questions about this topic, but looks like they aren't about what I'm looking for, so I did the question.

**First solution:**

`MyVendor/src/class/MyVendor/MyNamespace/Router.php` using 'intelligent' absolute path

```
namespace MyVendor\MyNamespace;

class Router
{
    private $root;
    private $cache;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setRootPath();
        $this->cache = "{$this->root}var/cache/";
    }

    public function setRootPath()
    {
        $currentDir = __DIR__;

        $exploded = explode("/", $currentDir);

        array_pop($exploded);   // Removing MyNamespace
        array_pop($exploded);   // Removing MyVendor
        array_pop($exploded);   // Removing class
        array_pop($exploded);   // Removing src

        $this->root = implode("/", $exploded)."/";
    }
}
```

**Second solution:**

`MyVendor/src/class/MyVendor/MyNamespace/Router.php` using relative path

```
namespace MyVendor\MyNamespace;

class Router
{
    private $root;
    private $cache;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setRootPath();
        $this->cache = "{$this->root}var/cache/";
    }

    public function setRootPath()
    {
        $this->root = __DIR__."/../../../../";
        // ..(pointing to MyVendor)/..(pointing to class)/..(pointing to src)/..(pointing to the root, MyVendor)
    }
}
```

Obs.3: See the first solution will use links like:

```
root => `/var/www/myproject/vendor/MyVendor/`

cache => `/var/www/myproject/vendor/MyVendor/var/cache`
```

and the second one will use links like:

```
root => `/var/www/myproject/vendor/MyVendor/src/class/MyVendor/MyNamespace/../../../../`

cache => `/var/www/myproject/vendor/MyVendor/src/class/MyVendor/MyNamespace/../../../../var/cache/`
```

Obs.4: the initial processing (using array_pop) is irrelevant to me.

So, what solution should I use and why? Is there another better way to do this (if yes, please write a Router class alternative)?

Comment: I like using absolute when possible, but I'd love to hear other people's reasoning.

Comment: You should use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` when exploding path (assuming your library could run on Windows systems)

Comment: good oint Uby, I'll edit

Comment: Also, why the second solution would output class path + relative path? If you don't prepend `__DIR__` it would not output that string (in that case relative path would be wrong)

Comment: Second proposed fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply ask for it?

```
namespace MyVendor\MyNamespace;

class Router
{
    private $root;
    private $cache;

    public function __construct($rootPath)
    {
        $this->root = $rootPath;
        $this->cache = "{$this->root}var/cache/";
    }
}
```

Injecting the root path allow the clients of your library to put it (physically) anywhere they want. In your exemple, you suppose the root path is 4 dir up; What if it is not the case?

Comment: You propose to pass the rootpath as argument? But I'd like configure the root path automatically, no passing arguments. The router will be one of the first things that I will run.

Comment: Why is your router needing a path anyway? You should really consider using autoloading.

Comment: Alfwed, if you're using composer (and that is will be the case, my internal structure should be keep). You could put the lib in myproject/lib or in my project/vendor ... but my cache folder, for example, will always be in `MyVendor/var/cache`

Comment: If you're using composer then use composer's autoloading and you won't need the root path.

Comment: I think yes, if not, how can I know the root path? becuase the autoload will keep something like "psr-0" : {"class": "src"}.The autoload will not know where is the cache folder (because at this folder will not have classes, just cache files).

Comment: If you really need it, again I would ask for it to allow more reusability. If you want to tie your code with the composer architecture then I would go with your second solution but I think it's always best to defer this kind of choices for as long as possible.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd definitely use `realpath()` on your relative path work if you decide to use it (simplifies it for the developers and makes it easier to predict).

Second, I'd dispense with your array_pop() technique, that will fall apart real fast if you decide to reorganize things.

I'd opt for a `preg_replace('#^'.$FS_ROOT.'#', __FILE__);` type approach to determine what's being called.

I think you should look at a reverse in your flow of information and pass in the 'base' of your project and then determine everything from there. This would save you a great headache when you move it around or have multiple copies of that code running for development.

Comment: The first propose will be the same thing as use __DIR__?  and the second proposer, $FS_ROOT is the same thing as $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]? If yes, I had a problem when trying to use this